# Method (Action) call in Task.Factory.StartNew not being invoked immediately

Tags: c#, multithreading, taskfactory

I was under the impression that I could just make this thread call and whatever was in my method "DoSomething" would just start happening, but apparently not.

When I invoke this line:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
ControllerClass.DoSomething("data"), 
CancellationToken.None, 
TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

ControllerClass.DoSomething("data") is not executed.

However, if I add a Wait, then the method gets called.

The reason I'm using the LongRunning option is that the method can be LongRunning in certain things aren't in place when it start executing. And yes, the the method itself works when called inline. It is just that it needs to be in a thread so that the main program can continue while this thread does its thing.

By the way, I have also tried this way to call it and same results:

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 ControllerClass.DoSomething("data")).ContinueWith
        (t =>
        {
            SendErrorEmail(t.Exception);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
        );
```

Am I missing some option to tell it to start executing the method call right away?

Comment: Note that your task is always executed no matter you wait for task or not.

Comment: Invoking stuff on another thread (especially when you delegate this to someone else) isn't deterministic--you can't know when it is going to happen.  It'll happen, like, whenever, so you know, like, chill out and stuff.

Comment: It should happen immediately unless you are out of threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was under the impression that I could just make this thread call and
>   whatever was in my method "DoSomething" would just start happening,
>   but apparently not.

No, this is not happening. Actually, when you write this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    ControllerClass.DoSomething("data"), 
    CancellationToken.None, 
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

under the cover your task is  get into a queue and sooner or later will be run on a thread of the `ThreadPool`.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782533(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Calling StartNew is functionally equivalent to creating a
>   Task using one of its constructors and then calling Start to
>   schedule it for execution.

Ragarding you other statement:

> However, if I add a Wait, then the method gets called.

This is true, because the `TaskFactory.StartNew` returns a `Task` object. when we call the `Wait` method of a task

> If the current task has not started execution, the Wait method
>   attempts to remove the task from the scheduler and execute it inline
>   on the current thread. If it is unable to do that, or if the current
>   task has already started execution, it blocks the calling thread until
>   the task completes.

In a few words `Wait` is a blocking action.

Please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on this.

> Am I missing some option to tell it to start executing the method call
>   right away?

No. Unless calling wait there isn't any alternative, as far as I am aware of.

Comment: Ok. But when I call this in unit test, the unit test ends, and nothing happens. I would think that because this is a child thread of the main caller, that the program wouldn't just end until the thread has had a chance to do something, even if I don;t call Wait.

Comment: @user1013388 It runs on a background thread, so the main thread will end without waiting for it.

Comment: Default task scheduler use dedicated thread (not thread pool) for tasks with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` option.